# Traverse every unique path (from root to leaf) in an arbitrary tree structure

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have several lists:

```
A = ["a0", "a1"]       // the number of lists varies
B = ["b0", "b1", "b2"] // such as the number of elements in a list.
C = ["c1"]
D = ["d0", "d1"]
```

I convert this structure into a tree:

```
             _____ROOT______
            /               \ 
       ___a0____        ____a1____
      /    |    \      /     |    \
    b0    b1    b2    b0    b1    b2
     |     |     |     |     |     |
    c1    c1    c1    c1    c1    c1
   / |   / |   / |   / |   / |   / |
  d0 d1 d0 d1 d0 d1 d0 d1 d0 d1 d0 d1
```

I'm printing every unique path in the tree (omitting the root):

```
a0 -> b0 -> c1 -> d0
a0 -> b0 -> c1 -> d1
a0 -> b1 -> c1 -> d0
...
a1 -> b2 -> c1 -> d1
```

I'm doing this by "destroying" the tree itself while traversing it in the following way:

```java
public static void delete(Node node) {
  if (node.isLeaf() && !node.isRoot()) {
    Node parent = node.getParent();
    parent.removeChild(node);
    delete(parent);
  }
}

public static void traverse(Node node) {
  if (node.isRoot())
    System.out.println("---");
  else
    System.out.println(node.getName());

  if (node.isLeaf()) {    // I'm still working on
    if (!node.isRoot()) { // removing unnecessary checks
      delete(node);
      traverse(node.getRoot());
    }
  } else {
    Node child = node.firstChild();
    if (null != child)
      traverse(child);
  }
}
```

`traverse(Node)` always prints the first available path of the tree (from root to leaf) while `delete(Node)` cuts leafs of the tree that is already visited by `traverse(Node)`.

This works as intended, but I'm keen to find a solution to traverse the tree in the previously described way without destroying it.
If there's a way to do this then I'd be interested to traverse this same structure, but in the form of a graph to reduce redundancy.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

OK. I think you actually mean that you want to find every path from root to a leaf.

Then (a un-optimized version)

```
void traverse (Node root) {
  // assume root != NULL
  traverse (root, new LinkedList<Node>());
}

private void traverse (Node root, LinkedList<Node> path) {
  path.add(root);
  if (root.isLeaf()) {
    print path;
  }
  else {
    for each node of root {
      traverse (node, new LinkedList<Node>(path));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: how can you do this with javascript?

Comment: Little code added to make the function return all the paths. Thanks anyways. :)

Answer (score 2):

So basically you are doing a depth first search, but rather than tracking the visiting of the nodes explicitly in a non-destructive way, or maintaining enough context to search without tracking, you are destroying the tree to do this tracking.

The traditional way to convert this to a plain DFS would be to loop around your recursion condition, basically change the child recursive call to something like:

```
} else {
  for (Node child = node.firstChild(); node != null; node = node.nextChild()) {
      traverse(child);
  }
}
```

This will traverse all your children, and you can pretty much remove the node.isLeaf case, since backtracking is done automatically for you.  Note that I made up the `nextChild` function since I can't see what it's called in your code, but you must have something similar, or some way to iterate through the children.

An alternate way that preserves more of the structure of your existing code would be to maintain a separate data structure which contains a set of "visited" nodes, this could be as simple as a Set of strings if all your node names are unique - rather than delete the node, add it to the "visited" set, and in your recursion condition, don't check for null, but rather find the first unvisited node.  This is probably more complicated than the suggestion above, but might be more similar to what you have now - and would avoid loops in the case you ever need to do this on a cyclic graph rather than a tree.

Comment: In addition to this, you may want to generally read up on Breadth-First Search and Depth-First Search.

Comment: The solution presented in the snippet works if I'm destroying my tree (or its copy), but that wasn't my intention. The second idea indeed is the best solution as I saw right now, but Dante Jiang presented an elegant solution for that, this is why I can't accept your answer. Thanks anyway!

Comment: FWIW, the solution in the snippet wasn't intended to be used with tree destruction, as the comments immediately after it explain - it is in fact the same solution as presented by Dante Jiang.

Answer (score 1):

Something that I came up with working on printing the words in a TrieTree that can be easily adaptable to other kinds of trees or different needs:

```
public void rootToLeaves() {
    HashMap<Integer, TrieNode> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, TrieNode>();
    for(TrieNode trieNode : root.getChildren())
        rootToLeaves(trieNode, hashMap, 0);
}

private void rootToLeaves( TrieNode trieNode, HashMap<Integer, TrieNode> hashMap, int heightIndex ) {
    hashMap.put(heightIndex, trieNode);

    if( trieNode.isLeaf() )
        printValues(hashMap, heightIndex);
    else
        for( TrieNode childNode : trieNode.getChildren() )
            rootToLeaves( childNode, hashMap, heightIndex + 1 );
}

private void printValues(HashMap<Integer, TrieNode> hashMap, int heightIndex) {
    for(int index = 0; index <= heightIndex; index++)
        System.out.print(hashMap.get(index).getValue());
    System.out.println();
}
```

This solution does a nice job in terms of memory management (It uses a single `HashMap` whose size will never exceed the height of the tree) and it offers a lot of flexibility (Just replace printValues with whatever you need).

NOTE: Knowing the height of the tree in advance will let you use a simple `Array` instead of a `Map`.

Answer (score 0):

1,Find leaf node
2,Up traversal from leaf node

```
public void printPath(N n) {
        if (n == null)
            return;
        if (n.left == null && n.right == null) {
            do {
                System.out.print(n.value);
                System.out.print(" ");
            } while ((n = n.parent) != null);
            System.out.println("");
            return;
        }
        printPath(n.left);
        printPath(n.right);
    }
```

printPath(Root);